# Sharepoint to Sharepoint - Power Flow: How to update "manager's name" based on user's name in the *same* item when item is created or modified?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate

**My Objective:**

I am trying to auto populate manager's field using flow at preview.flow.microsoft.com in a SharePoint lists. How can I achieve this

1- Add or modify item like below

[image: Displaying the automation]
2- Enter user's name

3- Manager's name should automatically add based on user's name in same item.

**My research:**
I looked at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#get-manager-(v2)

I tried to create this but as you can see, it is trying to update more than just one field.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this so this post has helped me tremendously and I've managed to replicate it exactly and it works as intended. Now my question is when I create or edit any single row in my List it runs a flow for **ALL** items in the list at one time rather than just the row created or modified (image below). My list will eventually have many thousands of rows so I'd ideally like to only run the manager update flow for the row created/edited, is this possible? EDIT: It looks like the flow runs irrespective of if any changes are made almost like a scheduled flow? I've had to turn off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, the “**Get Manager V2**” works with Azure directory and not SharePoint Online.

**Please following steps:**

1.Sign in **[Azure Active Directory admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com/)** as Global Administrators, and make sure that the user has **Manager** information.

[image]

2.Create the Microsoft Flow

[image]

3.Save and Test flow

4.When you create new item in the list, the corresponding **Manager's Name** will be automatically filled in.

[image]

========================= **Updated Answer** =======================

**Please following steps:**

**Solution A:**

1.Add column to your list. For example, add [Status] (Choice column) and set default value is Pending.

[image]

2.In order to avoid endless loops, you can set conditions: update item when [Status] is Pending, and change [Status] to Completed. Then it will jump out of the next cycle.

[image]

**Solution B：**

Add **Condition** action to the Microsoft Flow:

- Manager's Name Claims is equal to null

Or

- Manager's Name Claims is not equal Display Name

[image]

Comment: It does the lookup but it just keeps running infinitely when checked "All runs" history
It gave this warning for "Update Item" : "Actions in this flow may result in an infinite trigger loop ..."

Comment: How do I put a condition where it should update only if manager's name is not correct?

Comment: Hi SunMan. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!